# Sinon stub chained methods

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, kue

I have the following code in my SailsJs controller:

```
Jobs.create('beginImport', {
    version: version
}).save(function(err){
    if(err) {
        return res.serverError(err);
    }
    res.ok({ info: "import started" });
});
```

And in my test I am trying to stub `Jobs` like this:

```
var save = { save: sinon.stub() };
sinon.stub(Jobs, "create").returns(save);
```

However my test times out after 2000 ms and fails.

How can I stub these methods so that the test passes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stub should call the function that is passed to it using [stub.callsArg(index);](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) or related functions.

```
var save = { save: sinon.stub() };
```

should become

```
var save = { save: sinon.stub().callsArg(0) };
```

if you don't need to pass in any parameters, or

```
var save = { save: sinon.stub().callsArgWith(0, new Error('error')) };
```

if you need to test the error.

Comment: Good to hear, sinon is a great tool if you know how to use it.